# Pass Whole Table As Parameter Of SP In C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I want to pass the whole table like `DS.TABLE(0)` as a parameter of a Stored Procedure.

Please explain how I can do this.

I am using SQL Server 2005

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you are trying to do ? How is the table populated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 has [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx), just for this thing, but since you are using SQL Server 2005 you can't use them.

An option it to pass in XML and parse it on the server. This is an expensive operation, so you need to test.

You can find lots of information on how to pass in lists and arrays to SQL Server 2005 [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-perftest.html) (Erland Sommarskog), complete with performance and other comparisons.

Comment: @Ajay - I believe I have answered your question. You didn't say "don't tell me what I already know", nor did you say what you already know. The article I have linked to details several ways to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass a .Net Framework `DataTable` instance into a SQL Server 2005 stored procedure. This is possible in SQL Server 2008.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=SQL.100).aspx

Comment: You should clarify that there's no way... on SQL server 2005 but it is definitely possible on SQL server 2008

Comment: I Know that ,This Is Possible in sql server 2008,But I want to know Is This Possible in SQL Server 2005

Comment: That is why I have stated - "There is no way". Obviously this is not the answer you wanted, but it is the answer.